# Implement an Objective-C protocol in an Objective-C++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c, protocols

Say I've got an Objective-C protocol:

```
@protocol XYZPieChartViewDataSource
    - (NSUInteger)numberOfSegments;
    - (CGFloat)sizeOfSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
    - (NSString *)titleForSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@end
```

How would I implement this in an Objective-C++ class (.mm)?

Comment: It shouldn't be (much) different.  Your Objective-C++ class is still Objective-C - the @interface should look like any other Objective-C class that implements a protocol.  The .mm file is where things can be different, where you can use C++ objects in the body of your methods

Comment: My .mm file is implementing a C++-style class. Everything in it uses c++ syntax, except for some calls to the SDK that contains the @protocol.
Can my c++ class implement this @protocol? If so, how?

Comment: You might need to add an extra layer of indirection (writing on obj-c class that implements the protocol that delegates the implementations to the c++ class)